# CAML Query to sort a blog Posts list by published date

Tags: 2013, list, caml-query, sorting

I have successfully created a CAML query to sort my list by modified date but I want published date instead.  Why does replacing "Modified" with "Published" not work?  They are both "Date and Time" columns in the list when I look at List Settings but the published column must have a different name for some reason?  (This is in SharePoint 2013)

```
query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='False'/><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='True'></Value></OrderBy>";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The internal name of the field is PublishedDate.  Try changing your query to use that name and hopefully that will solve the problem.